# Is there any other way to add an ActionListener to a button using windowbuilder (eclipse) in design mode than to double click on the button?

Tags: java, eclipse, actionlistener, windowbuilder

I'm new to windowbuilder designer with eclipse. I'm using eclipse 2021-12, jdk 17 and windowbuilder 1.9.8 version.
I'm trying to add an actionListener on a button in design mode. But when I double-click on this button in design mode, to add an actionListener, nothing happens.

Here is my source code in source mode :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;

public class SwingApp {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SwingApp window = new SwingApp();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public SwingApp() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnClick = new JButton("Click");
        btnClick.setBackground(new Color(219, 112, 147));
        btnClick.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        btnClick.setFont(new Font("Inconsolata SemiBold", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnClick.setBounds(165, 101, 118, 51);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnClick);
    }
}
```

And here is the rendering in design mode : [the rendering in design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y8Lt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Righ-click on the button and add an event handler. You want to add a mouse event handler.

[image]